# How can I select an element from an jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

Say I have the following code:

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="t1">A</div>
  <div class="t2">B</div>
</div>

//JS

var obj = $('.foo');
```

Now I want to get the text from t2 element. How do I select this using my `obj` object?

This does **not** work: `var txt = $(obj + '.t2').text();`
This works fine: `var txt = obj.find('.t2').text();`
I also know I can use this `var txt = $('.foo .t2').text();`

But I'm thinking that using `.find()` requires more resources than selecting it directly. Is there a way I can select child element directly using my `obj` ?

Comment: The amount of resources you're referring to is negligible in your example. You could always do it like this http://jsfiddle.net/L0h1uq2e/

Comment: If you know it's a child, you can use `.children('.t2')` and it will only search through the element's children.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking this an attempt at a time:

```
var txt = $(obj + '.t2').text();
```

This does not work because you are trying to append a string to an object, the result of which will not be a valid selector.

```
var txt = obj.find('.t2').text();
```

This will look for the `.t2` element within the cached subset of elements in the original selector. This is the best method to use for your scenario and actually uses less resources than example 3:

```
var txt = $('.foo .t2').text();
```

which will also work, however it will require jQuery to scan the DOM again, which is something which should be avoided where possible.

Comment: One more option is `$('.t2', obj).text();`

Comment: @u_mulder that's true, but if memory serves that syntax is just syntactic sugar for the `.find()` method.

Comment: So it better to use `.find()` rather than scanning the whole DOM again?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
 obj.children().eq(1).text()
```

This way you access the children of your `obj` variable, take the second (0 based index) and access its text.

Answer (score 0):

If your condition is that you have to go through your `obj` element, then I believe `find()` is the way to go.  I didn't see anything in jQuery's documentation on find() regarding if it's efficiency vs a direct selector, but I think the fact that you're only searching descendents of your `obj` with `find()` means it can't be too inefficient.

```
obj.find('.t2').text()
```

Comment: You don't need to use `$()` since `obj`is already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to select children would be to get all children and access them by index:

```
var ch = obj.children();
var text = ch.eq(1).text();
```

This naturally means that you have to know the order of the child elements.

You can use a selector in the [`children` method](http://api.jquery.com/children/). That will get the children that matches the selector, but the only difference from using `find` is that it only looks for immediate children, so in your case it works the same:

```
var text = obj.children('.t2').text();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using this all over the place and the elemnt might be deeper in the DOM of `obj`. So using `.find()` is better.